# How do I access an property from an object within another object from another file in Qt?

Tags: qt, qml

let's say I have two files:

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    color: pRect.color

    Red{
        id:pRect
    }
}
```

and Red.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle {
    id: pRect
    color: "red"
    Rectangle{
        id: cRect
        color: "blue"
    }
}
```

where main.qml uses the colour of the parent rectangle 'pRect' from Red.qml. However, if I now wanted to use the colour of the child rectangle 'cRect', I'd try something like.

```
color: pRect.cRect.color
```

but that doesn't work, is there a way for me to access that colour value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#the-id-attribute):

> An object can be referred to by its id from anywhere within the component scope in which it is declared.

That is, `pRect` and `cRect` have no meaning outside of `Red.qml`.

**So why can pRect be used in main.qml?** Because you have created an item with the same name, if you create another Red item you will have to place another id:

```
Red{
    id:pRect
}

Red{
    id:pRect2
}
```

So it thinks it is broken now that: what is the pRect?

---

So the only solution is to expose the property of the child as property of the parent:

**Red.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9

Rectangle {
    id: root
    property alias childcolor: child.color
    color: "red"
    Rectangle{
        id: child
        color: "blue"
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    color: pRect.childcolor
    Red{
        id:pRect
    }
}
```

---

So in conclusion the properties of the children of the root element of a component are private, and if you want to use it outside you have to expose it using a root property.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the solution I neeeded